# Why is multi step docker build better?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I have been updating our dotnet core application from dotnet 2.0 to 2.1 and I see that multi step dockerfiles are now suggested. I read that it is more efficent to build your app inside a container with the dotnet SDK and then copy to a different container with just the runtime. https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/18

I am wondering why this would be better that how we did it with our 2.0 images which would be to run `dotnet publish MySolution.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish` on our build server (dotnet 2.1 sdk is installed on it) and then do a single step build where we copy the build output to an image.

It is claimed to be simpler to do a multi step build, but it seems more complicated to me to copy over everything you need for a build, and then copy the results to another container.

Here is what the multi step Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY myproject.csproj app/
RUN dotnet restore myproject.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Setting
RUN dotnet restore myproject.csproj
RUN dotnet build myproject.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish myproject.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject.dll"]
```

vs a single step one.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Myproject.dll"]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: With the former you only have the runtime dependencies in the deployed container, whereas with the single file you need everything to build *and* run it. If you were already building outside, then just continue to do that.

Comment: Fair enough, we were always building outside the container, so we will just stick to a single step Dockerfile where we copy the build results to the runtime container

Answer (score 1):

> I read that it is more efficent to build your app inside a container with the dotnet SDK and then copy to a different container with just the runtime.

I believe that this description already exists before .Net Core 2.1 in the official documentation of Docker.

This is simply because you need SDK only to build your application, but if you have already built the application somewhere else, you can directly run it on runtime container (not SDK container). I did that a lot when no SDK were available for ARM processors, I had to build the application on my PC, then had to copy it to the target device. That was not that easy, because I always had dependencies problems, which I had to solve manually.

Therefore, it is almost always recommended to build the application on the machine you want to deploy the app on. This guaranties that your application will be build with the proper settings for that exact software and hardware requirements.

Because of that, I would always build the application on the target deploying device (on SDK container), and then copy the output of building to runtime container.

Now you are asking: why not simply run the application in SDK container? The only reason is probably because it will be significantly larger and heavier than any runtime container (as it has runtime environment + building tools).

Comment: That is an interesting explanation, I could see the benefits of building inside a container because you want to deploy inside a container. For now it is simpler for us to build on our build server and copy over the results. If we run into problems like you had then we could switch to building on a sdk container.

Comment: @Cale Actually it is not simpler, I find using Docker SDK container is very much straight forward and make the life very much easy and organized, I use Docker intensively for every single service on my development, staging, and production servers (including .Net Core service). I automated every single step, from copying my project to the target server, to running the SDK container with the copied files. I.e., I only run one script on my device, I wait a couple of seconds, then everything is ready for me!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just using a single stage build because we can build the app on our CI server. The CI server has the SDK installed but our container just uses the runtime image. Building from the SDK image could be interesting if you don't have the dotnet sdk available, or you want to build on a container.

Here is what my Dockerfile looks like for 2.1:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY Microservices/FooService/Foo/obj/Docker/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Foo.dll"]
```